# Oracle Scheduler run time time-zone dependent?

Tags: oracle, timezone, scheduler

If I change the time zone of my local machine, will it affect the Oracle Scheduler's next run time??

Answer (score 0):

schedule jobs run from the time on the system clock of the server, so changing the timezone changes the system clock and therefore the next scheduled time

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Oracle scheduler takes the timezone from the session, unless you specify a start date (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE). If you want to change the timezone of a scheduled job, use dbms_scheduler.set_attribute and give a new start_date with the timezone you want. Check by looking at the next run date in DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS, which is also of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.